# Play a music when WiFi is disconnected

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-wifi

I'm trying to write the codes for my project that's to play a music when WiFi connection is disconnected and also whenever user clicks 'test' button it display the current connection strength.  I've tried the following code:

Main activity part (for the test button and call out the class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "Final Year Project";
    private static boolean wifiConnected = false;
    private static boolean mobileConnected = false;

    private LogFragment mLogFragment;

    private AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver alarm ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample_main);


    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(alarm, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // When the user clicks TEST, display the connection status.
            case R.id.test_action:
                checkNetworkStrengh();
                return true;
            // Clear the log view fragment.
            case R.id.clear_action:
                mLogFragment.getLogView().setText("");
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void checkNetworkStrengh() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo Info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (Info == null || !Info.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "No connection");
        } else {
            int netType = Info.getType();
            int netSubtype = Info.getSubtype();

            if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Wifi connection");
                WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                List<ScanResult> scanResult = wifiManager.getScanResults();
                for (int i = 0; i < scanResult.size();) {
                    Log.d("scanResult", "Speed of wifi" + scanResult.get(i).level);//The db level of signal //

                       // its okay now thanks guys //    
                }


            } else if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {

                Log.i(TAG, "GPRS/3G connection");

                // Need to get differentiate between 3G/GPRS
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver part (created in order to scan the current network connectivity all the time):

```
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static boolean wifiConnected = false;
    private static boolean mobileConnected = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo =
                intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // Wifi is connected
            Intent in = new Intent(context, RingService.class);
            context.stopService(in);
        } else {
            Intent in = new Intent(context, RingService.class);
            context.startService(in);

        }
    }

}
```

and the MusicService part(created in order to play a music whenever the class AlarmMAnagerBroadcastReceiver triggered the specific condition):

```
public class MusicService extends Service{

    private MediaPlayer mp;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    mp.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        mp.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          try {
                    mp.release();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MusicService.this, R.raw.ly);
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Manifest file

```js
        <service
            android:name="com.example.android.basicnetworking.RingService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":remote" >
        </service>
            
                    <receiver android:name=".AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="100" android:enabled="true"
                android:label="ConnectivityActionReceiver">
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
```

Can someone who's professional in android programming helps me in the code cause i'm new in android and java programming) to get return to checkConnectivity class in the AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver part, and also to play a music when the wifi connection is lost.

Edit: thanks for the helps. I have figured it out. If anyone need the codes you can inbox me or I will upload the complete coding once everything is ok.

Edit: updated some code

Comment: Refer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888502/how-to-detect-when-wifi-connection-has-been-established-in-android) to get wifi is connected or disconnected

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki he already got that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting WiFi signal strength in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932724/getting-wifi-signal-strength-in-android)

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki thanks man, I am refering that right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int numberOfLevels = 5;
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(), numberOfLevels);
```

When you try to play the music AGAIN, then you need to prepare it again, so every time before start call prepare as well:

add this to AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver:

```
void play(int musicId) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), musicId);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
}
```

and in checkConnectivity where you want to play music:

```
play(R.raw.ly); // or use other resource instead of ly
```

Comment: i need a code in checkConnectivity class in the AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver activity, can u help me a fav?

Answer (score 0):

play sound on disconnection... try this:

```
       public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
            static boolean isConnect = false;

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d(TAG, "network changed");
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (activeNetwork != null) { // connected to the internet
                    if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "network type wifi"); // connected on wifi

                    } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "network type mobile"); // connected on mobile (3g/4g)
                    }
                } else {
                    isConnect = false;
                    Log.d(TAG, "no connection"); // DISCONNECTED
                    playMySound(); // <- your play sound function
                }

            }

            public void playMySound() {
                MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.song);
                sound.start();
            }
       }
```

Comment: I get this error: cannot resolve symbol 'context', in the declaration MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.song); , i tried many ways to resolve but it didnt work

Comment: I'hv fixed this issue by using the another way.