# android scan all wifi network and list ssid

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi, ssid

I want to list all wifi network and show ssid in a list.I think I should use broadcast to do this but I used several codes but doesnt work .I just need to list all ssides and show them to user but if you tell me how can show wifi signal stronge too it will be greate.
I use this code but doesnt work:

```
    public class WiFiDemo extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    WifiManager wifi;
    ListView lv;
    TextView textStatus;
    Button buttonScan;
    int size = 0;
    List<ScanResult> results;

    String ITEM_KEY = "key";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    SimpleAdapter adapter;

    /* Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wifidemo);

        textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
        buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
        buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        wifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
        this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(WiFiDemo.this, arraylist, R.layout.row, new String[]{ITEM_KEY}, new int[]{R.id.list_value});
        lv.setAdapter(this.adapter);

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
                results = wifi.getScanResults();
                size = results.size();
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        arraylist.clear();
        wifi.startScan();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning...." + size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            size = size - 1;
            while (size >= 0) {
                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                item.put(ITEM_KEY, results.get(size).SSID + "  " + results.get(size).capabilities);

                arraylist.add(item);
                size--;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see this answer in the post i think it help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7527380/2818627

Comment: this code exactly is the same

Comment: and for get wifi signal strength you can use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30901663/2818627[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30901663/2818627)

Answer (score 0):

are you sure get this permissions?

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```