# How can i get wifi signal strength in Android Programmatically?

Tags: android, signals, wifi

Any one help me out to fetch wifi Signal strength ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932724/getting-wifi-signal-strength-in-android

Answer (score -1):

You can get the signal in levels by using:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int levels = 5;
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(), numberOfLevels);
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30901663/10445346) answer for further help.

Comment: is "levels" or "numberOfLevels"?