# how to frequently check if my wifi dBm level in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I am currently building an  android application that will soft handover the wifi connection from one Wifi access point to another when the signal level falls below a certain level. My question is how to write a code that frequently checks and monitors the dBm level in android studio?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (ScanResult result : wifiScanResultList) {
int signalLevel = result.level;
}
```

Take a look at this question:
[Getting WiFi signal strength in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13932724/10058326)

You can get the WIFI level using this and put this code in a background service which you can run according to how frequently you want to know the level

Comment: I have done this to get the scan results. I know that I can montor the dBm of the network that I am connected to using 
`WifiInfo info = myWifiManager.getConnectionInfo(); info.getRssi();`
my question is how to constantly monitor the dBm level of the connected network.
@Kunj Mehta

Comment: You can add a background service in your application that checks for wifi strength at certain intervals. Constant monitoring is a bad idea, drains the battery. Then when it falls below a certain level, use a broadcast listener linked to the service to perform a handvoer